# Copy constructors and copy assignement operators in cython

Tags: cython

I'm wrapping C++ classes in Python with Cython. Cython builds the shared library without problem (there are 3 warnings but I checked them and are apparently normal). The importing from Python works also well. But when I run the Python code I get a `Bus error` after the destructor of one of the classes is called. After some research, I found that `bus errors` are caused by a problem in memory management.

The first thing I thought is that there was a problem with my C++ pointers and classes. I wrote a `main.cpp` code similar to the Python one to reproduce a `Segmentation fault` but the program worked well.

From there I deduce that this is a cython problem. In my `.pxd` file I don't declare the copy constructor, the copy assignement operator  nor the destructor (I inspired my code from the Cython documentation). In my `.pyx` file I have a `__cinit__` and a `__dealloc__` method.

Does my problem come from the non-declaration of copy constructor and copy assignement operator in the Cython `cppclass`? If it does, how do I implement this methods in the `.pyx` file? I tried but Cython wouldn't recognize the symbols...

**cppCotest.h**

```
 #ifndef __CORAL2_H_INCLUDED__
 #define __CORAL2_H_INCLUDED__

 class CoralBranch{
   public:
     CoralBranch(); //nullary constructor
     CoralBranch(int st); //constructor
     ~CoralBranch(); //destructor
     CoralBranch(const CoralBranch&); //copy constructor
     CoralBranch& operator=(const CoralBranch&); //copy assignement
     CoralBranch *left; //Pointer to left child
     CoralBranch *right; //Pointer to right child
     int state;
   };

class Coral{
  public:
    Coral(); //constructor
    ~Coral(); //destructor
    Coral(const Coral&); //copy constructor
    Coral& operator=(const Coral&); //copy assignement
    void add_left(CoralBranch *leaf); //adds left son to coral-branch*leaf
    void add_right(CoralBranch *leaf); //adds right son to coral-branch *leaf
    void grow(CoralBranch *branch);
    CoralBranch *trunk;
   };

   #endif
```

**cppCotest.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "cppCotest.h"
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;

    CoralBranch::CoralBranch():left(NULL),right(NULL),state(1)
    {
    }

    CoralBranch::CoralBranch(int st):left(NULL),right(NULL),state(st)
    {
    }

    CoralBranch::~CoralBranch(){
      delete left;
      delete right;
    }

    CoralBranch::CoralBranch(const CoralBranch& cb){
      left=new CoralBranch(cb.left->state);
      right=new CoralBranch(cb.right->state);
      state=cb.state;
    }

    CoralBranch& CoralBranch::operator=(const CoralBranch& cb){
      if(this!=&cb){
        delete[] left;
        delete[] right;
        left=new CoralBranch(cb.left->state);
        right=new CoralBranch(cb.right->state);
        state=cb.state;
      }
      return *this;
    }

    Coral::Coral():trunk(new CoralBranch())
    {
    }

    Coral::~Coral(){
      delete trunk;
    }

    Coral::Coral(const Coral& c){
      trunk=new CoralBranch(c.trunk->state);
    }

    Coral& Coral::operator=(const Coral& c){

       if(this!=&c){
         delete[] trunk;
         trunk=new CoralBranch(c.trunk->state);
       }
       return *this;
     }

     void Coral::add_left(CoralBranch *leaf){
        leaf->left=new CoralBranch();
     }

     void Coral::add_right(CoralBranch *leaf){
        leaf->right=new CoralBranch();
     }

    void Coral::grow(CoralBranch *branch){

      if(branch!=NULL){

        if (branch->state==1){

          add_left(branch);
          add_right(branch);
          branch->state=0;
      }

      grow(branch->left);
      grow(branch->right);
    }
  }
```

**cyCotest.pxd**

```
#cython: language_level=3
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: cdivision=True
#distutils: language=c++

import sys
import cython

cdef extern from "cppCotest.h":

  cdef cppclass CoralBranch:
    CoralBranch() except +
    CoralBranch(int st) except +
    #CoralBranch(const CoralBranch&)
    #CoralBranch& operator=(const CoralBranch&)
    CoralBranch *left
    CoralBranch *right
    int state

  cdef cppclass Coral:
    Coral() except +
    #Coral(const Coral&)
    #Coral& operator=(const Coral&)
    void add_left(CoralBranch *leaf)
    void add_right(CoralBranch *leaf)
    void grow(CoralBranch *growingbranch)
    CoralBranch *trunk
```

**pyCotest.pyx**

```
#cython: language_level=3
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: cdivision=True
#distutils: language=c++
#distutils: sources=cppCotest.cpp

import sys
import cython
from cyCotest cimport Coral
from cyCotest cimport CoralBranch


cdef class PyCoral:
  cdef Coral c_coral
  def __cinit__(self):
    self.c_coral=Coral()
  c_coralbranch=PyCoralBranch(1)
  def add_left(self, PyCoralBranch leaf):
    self.c_coral.add_left(leaf.c_coralbranch)
  def add_right(self,PyCoralBranch leaf):
    self.c_coral.add_right(leaf.c_coralbranch)
  def grow(self,PyCoralBranch branch):
    self.c_coral.grow(branch.c_coralbranch)

cdef class PyCoralBranch:
  cdef CoralBranch* c_coralbranch
  def __cinit__(self,int st):
    self.c_coralbranch=new CoralBranch(st)
  def __dealloc__(self):
    del self.c_coralbranch
```

**pyCotestmain.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyCotest import PyCoral

N_generations=2

coral=PyCoral()

for i in range(N_generations):
    coral.grow(coral.trunk)
```

**setup.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "pyCotest",
        sources=["pyCotest.pyx", "cppCotest.cpp"],
        extra_compile_args=["-fopenmp","-fPIC"],
        extra_link_args=["-fopenmp"],
        language="c++",
    )
]

for e in ext_modules:
    e.pyrex_directives = {"boundscheck": False}

setup(
    name='Coral_library',
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules),
)
```

Comment: ...\Cython\Includes\libcpp contains the STL declaration examples, for example in vector.pxd `vector`'s copy-constructor `vector(vector&) except +`, but the copy-assignment operator is commented(I have no idea why) `#vector& operator=(vector&)`, I comment it out and it works fine. `cdef vector[int] v; v.push_back(1); cdef vector[int] vv; vv = v; print(v[0]); print(vv[0])`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will give it a try. I posted an example of code which reproduces the error if you want to take a look.

Comment: You're mixing up `new` with array `delete []` which is undefined behaviour. (`new` goes with `delete` and `new[n]` goes with `delete []`). Beyond that I don't know.

Comment: oz1 However, it doesn't really helps me since I don't know how to implement the copy constructor in the `.pyx`file

Comment: @DavidW : thank you for your remark. Indeed it solved my problem. I'm new with C++ and since I saw `delete[]` syntax in all the examples I looked, I thought I had to write it in that way. It's quite strange that the `main.cpp` program ran nevertheless

Comment: @bengo the thing with undefined behaviour is that it's often unreliable whether you get it or not. You can often get "lucky" and it doesn't happen.

Comment: The crash is indeed caused by `delete[]`. You can't implement the copy constructor in cython, you can just declare it in your `cdef cppclass Cls:` block for exposing to cython. Copy, assignment, destruction are all done under the cpp codes, cpp will take care of these mechanisms.